# Integrating react with django

Tags: reactjs, django, django-react

I am learning how to integrate react with Django.. I found the tutorial by Dennis Ivy useful.. (linked below).

So according to that video, where we create a Django project, and create a separate folder with `npx create-react-app appname`, we need to `npm run build` every time we make a change to the react.. Is there a better way to do it?

my settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'reactapp/build'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]



STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'reactapp/build/static'
]
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9o4GSkSo40&list=PLw4CVL8B1qWH_FsGE53Do_dSN-UdgGiGD&index=21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `create-react-app` is used, `npm run start` is a command you can use to host the `react` part of the application. This will start a server and host your application on `localhost:3000`.

In general you can check the `scripts` section of the `package.json` file for javascript packages, most application have their commands in this section, to run them on the cli and to run them you'd need to run `npm run <script name>`